# how to get multiple inputs spontaneously in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to make an html page with JavaScript inside it.
The idea is that, when someone selects the value of option from the select, it should generate automatically the fields of firstName, lastName etc depending on the number which is selected. If one is selected then it should have one field of firstName, lastName and if two is selected then it should generate two fields dynamically.

```
    <select id="noOfAuthor" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="one">1</option>
        <option value="two">2</option>
        <option value="three">3</option>
        <option value="four">4</option>
        <option value="five">5</option>

    </select>
```

If someone selects one then below there should be one code of

```
      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle1">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor1" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear1">
```

If we selects “2” then there should be two code asking

```
       Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle1">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor1" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear1">


      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle2">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor2" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear2">
```

And so on and so forth.

I tried to write a code for doing this, but it is not working.

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Book Collection</title>

<script language="JavaScript">
function WBook(bookName, writer, yearPublished)
{
    this.Title  = bookName;
    this.Author = writer;
    this.CopyrightYear = yearPublished;
}

function showBook(oneBook)
{
     var no = showChoices();
     var i ;
    for(i =0; i<no; i++)
    {
         document.frmBooks.txtTitle[i].value  = oneBook.Title[i];   
         document.frmBooks.txtAuthor[i].value = oneBook.Author[i];
         document.frmBooks.txtCopyrightYear[i].value = oneBook.CopyrightYear[i];
    }
 }

  function displayCollection()
  {
     var aBook = new WBook("Visual C++ From the Ground Up", "John Paul Mueller", 1998);
     showBook(aBook);   
  }

  function showChoices(){
    var noOfAuthor = document.getElementById("noOfAuthor");     
    var result = " You selected";
    result += " \n";

    for(i=0; i<noOfAuthor.length;i++){

         currentOption = noOfAuthor[i];
        if(currentOption.selected == true){
            result +=   currentOption.value + "\n";

         }
    }
    result += " \n";
    alert(result);
    return(result); 

    }
    </Script>
    </head>

   <body>


   <h1>Book Collection</h1>
   <form name="frmBooks">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" required="true" /><br> <br>
    <select id="noOfAuthor" >
        <option value="one">1</option>
        <option value="two">2</option>
        <option value="three">3</option>
        <option value="four">4</option>
        <option value="five">5</option>

    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="showChoices()">Submit</button>

      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle1">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor1" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear1">

      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle2">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor2" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear2">


        <p><input type="button" value="Show Collection" name="btnShow"            onClick="displayCollection()">

    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this (**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mj2ha/)**):

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Book Collection</title>

<script language="JavaScript">
function WBook(bookName, writer, yearPublished)
{
    this.Title  = bookName;
    this.Author = writer;
    this.CopyrightYear = yearPublished;
}

function showBook(oneBook)
{
     var no = showChoices();
     var i ;
    for(i =0; i<no; i++)
    {
         document.frmBooks.txtTitle[i].value  = oneBook.Title[i];   
         document.frmBooks.txtAuthor[i].value = oneBook.Author[i];
         document.frmBooks.txtCopyrightYear[i].value = oneBook.CopyrightYear[i];
    }
 }

  function displayCollection()
  {
     var aBook = new WBook("Visual C++ From the Ground Up", "John Paul Mueller", 1998);
     showBook(aBook);   
  }

  function showChoices(){
    var noOfAuthor = document.getElementById("noOfAuthor");     
    var result = " You selected";
    result += " \n";
    result += noOfAuthor.value

    for(i=1; i <= noOfAuthor.length;i++){

        if(i <= noOfAuthor.value){
            document.getElementById("inputs" + i).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("inputs" + i).style.display = 'none';
         }
    }
    result += " \n";
    alert(result);
    return(result); 

    }
    </Script>
    </head>

   <body>


   <h1>Book Collection</h1>
   <form name="frmBooks">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" required="true" /><br> <br>
    <select id="noOfAuthor" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>

    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="showChoices()">Submit</button>
    <div id="inputs1">
      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle1">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor1" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear1">
    </div>
    <div id="inputs2" style="display:none">
      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle2">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor2" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear2">
    </div>
    <div id="inputs3" style="display:none">
      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle3">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor3" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear3">
    </div>
    <div id="inputs4" style="display:none">
      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle4">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor4" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear4">
    </div>
    <div id="inputs5" style="display:none">
      Title Name <input type="text" name="txtTitle5">
      Author Name <input type="text" name="txtAuthor5" >
      Copy right<input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear5">
    </div>


        <p><input type="button" value="Show Collection" name="btnShow"            onClick="displayCollection()">

    </form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detail explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

very simple with jquery:

```
    <select id="noOfAuthor" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>

    </select>
    <div id="inputs"></div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("select#noOfAuthor > option").click(function() {
        $( "#noOfAuthor" ).attr("disabled", true);
        var howMuch = parseInt($( "#noOfAuthor" ).val());
        for(i = 0; i < howMuch; i++) {
               $( "#inputs" ).append('Title Name: <input type="text" name="txtTitle' + i + '"><br>Author Name: <input type="text" name="txtAuthor' + i + '"><br>Copy right: <input type="text" name="txtCopyrightYear' + i + '"><br><hr />');
        }
    });

});
```

So you get inputs as the selected number.
the Three first willl be:

- name="txtTitle0"
- name="txtAuthor0"
- name="txtCopyrightYear0"

### demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mxgbc/3/

Comment: thank you so much. I want to be geek like you guys so that I can help others too !!
Thanks you once again.

Comment: Can you explain me please, how it is working? How and where to use apostrophe and double quotations. I am quite confused in the line of #input

Answer (score 0):

I would generate the inputs and labels dynamically. This is a pure javascript example, without using jQuery. I can provide a jQuery solution if you need it.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/A62qA/1 // basic select menu

Example http://jsfiddle.net/A62qA/2/ // mutiple choice select menu

HTML

```
<select id="noOfAuthor" onchange="inputFunction(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div id="myContainer"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function createInputs(i) {
        var myContainer = document.getElementById("myContainer");
        var titleName = document.createElement("input");
            titleName.setAttribute('name', 'txtTitle1' + i);
        var label = document.createElement("Label");
            label.innerHTML = "Title Name";
            myContainer.appendChild(label);
            myContainer.appendChild(titleName);

        var authorName = document.createElement("input");
            authorName.setAttribute('name', 'txtAuthor1' + i);
        var label = document.createElement("Label");
            label.innerHTML = "Author Name";
            myContainer.appendChild(label);
            myContainer.appendChild(authorName);

        var copyRight = document.createElement("input");
            copyRight.setAttribute('name', 'txtCopyrightYear1' + i);
        var label = document.createElement("Label");
            label.innerHTML = "CopyRight";
            myContainer.appendChild(label);
            myContainer.appendChild(copyRight);
    }

    function inputFunction(y) {
        var y = y.value;
        var myContainer = document.getElementById("myContainer");
        for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            createInputs(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! one thing could be done by so many different ways! For me this looks a bit advance as my level is low as for now. 
Thanks for sharing this, which makes me realize I need to learn so many things!